# New to coding and working an example in the book which was written for xcode 6.2 and I have the newest version.

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I get the following error when I run the app and try and click any key on the keypad that opens on launch. 
Here is the error I get in the attached photo [image: photo of error]

Below is my code and it highlights the first func at the bottom called func formatAsCurrancy... as the problem area. I have converted all the old code in the book as it prompted me to. Not sure what to do at this point. Thank you for any help.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //properties for programmatically interacting with UI components
    @IBOutlet weak var billAmountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var customTipPercentLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var customTipPercentageSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var customTipPercentLabel2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tip15Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var total15Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tipCustomLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalCustomLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputTextField: UITextField!

    // NSDecimalNumber constants used in the calculateTip method
    let decimal100 = NSDecimalNumber(string: "100.0")
    let decimal15Percent = NSDecimalNumber(string: "0.15")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        // select inputTextField so keypad displays when the view loads 
        inputTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func calculateTip(_ sender: Any) {
        let inputString = inputTextField.text //get user input

        // convert slider value to an NSDecimalNumber
        let sliderValue =
            NSDecimalNumber(integerLiteral: Int(customTipPercentageSlider.value))

        // divide sliderValue by decimal100 (100.0) to get tip %
        let customPercent = sliderValue / decimal100

        // did customTipPercentageSlider generate the event?
        if sender is UISlider {
            // thumb moved so update the Labels with new custom percent
            customTipPercentLabel1.text =
                NumberFormatter.localizedString(from: customPercent,
                                                number: NumberFormatter.Style.percent)
            customTipPercentLabel2.text = customTipPercentLabel1.text
        }

        // if there is a bill amount, calculate tips and totals
        if !(inputString?.isEmpty)! {
            // convert to NSDecimalNumber and insert decimal point
            let billAmount =
                NSDecimalNumber(string: inputString) / decimal100

            // did inputTextField generate the event?
            if sender is UITextField {
                billAmountLabel.text = " " + formatAsCurrency(number: billAmount)

                // calculate and display the 15% tip and total
                let fifteenTip = billAmount * decimal15Percent
                tip15Label.text = formatAsCurrency(number: fifteenTip)
                total15Label.text =
                    formatAsCurrency(number: billAmount + fifteenTip)
                }

            // calculate custom tip and display custom tip and total
            let customTip = billAmount * customPercent
            tipCustomLabel.text = formatAsCurrency(number: customTip)
            totalCustomLabel.text =
                formatAsCurrency(number: billAmount + customTip)
        }
        else {// clear all Labels
            billAmountLabel.text = ""
            tip15Label.text = ""
            total15Label.text = ""
            tipCustomLabel.text = ""
            totalCustomLabel.text = ""
        }
    }

}

// convert a numeric value to localized currency string 
func formatAsCurrency(number: NSNumber) -> String {
    return NumberFormatter.localizedString(
        from: number, number: NumberFormatter.Style.currency)
}
// overloaded + operator to add NSDecimalNumbers
func +(left: NSDecimalNumber, right: NSDecimalNumber) -> NSDecimalNumber {
    return left.adding(right)
}
// overloaded * operator to multiply NSDecimalNumbers
func *(left: NSDecimalNumber, right: NSDecimalNumber) -> NSDecimalNumber {
    return left.multiplying(by: right)
}
// overloaded / operator to divide NSDecimalNumbers
func /(left: NSDecimalNumber, right: NSDecimalNumber) -> NSDecimalNumber {
    return left.dividing(by: right)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simulator is trying to find a numeric keyboard on your computer, but your computer shouldn't have one so that's why it's giving you the error.

If you go to the simulator and then Hardware -> Keyboard -> Uncheck use hardware keyboard, the issue will go away.

Comment: When I made the change it worked once. When I closed the sim and ran it again I get the same error. I also noticed that my slider doesn't work either.

Comment: Only the "can't find keyplane" warning will disappear with my solution. The other text is just a bug with iOS 10, and there's nothing you can do about it. Also, your slider shouldn't be affected at all by this change.

Comment: The error went away once but when I tried to run the program again it freezes and I can't input any values with the keypad. It only worked the first time I did what you said.